# Changing network interface not working after reboot

Tags: linux, debian, networking, bridge

In my dedicated server (Debian Jessie) network interface code looks as follows.

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address xxx.xxx.xxx.194
        netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.248
        network xxx.xxx.xxx.192
        broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.199
        gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.193
        dns-nameservers 127.0.0.1
        dns-search nocix.net
```

But after changing interface as shown below:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address xxx.xxx.xxx.194
    netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.248
    network xxx.xxx.xxx.192
    broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.199
    gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.193
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 9
    bridge_hello 2
    bridge_maxage 12
```

Everything works after restarting the network interface (`service networking restart`). But when I reboot I am unable to connect via SSH.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue with Lubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I purged ssh with

```
sudo apt-get purge openssh-server
```

and promptly reinstalled with

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

I was then able to connect with ssh again.

If you have customized the `sshd_config` (or any other ssh config file) be sure to make a backup copy in a safe location before purging because a purge removes all config files, where a remove does not.